# Typescript imports of submodules not found errors for mapbox-sdk-js

Tags: typescript, mapbox, definitelytyped

I've stumbled across a strange behavior in typescript imports when using `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk`. I've installed both `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` and `@types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk`. The code itself works. The issue is strictly the typing.

First I tried the following imports:

```js
import { MapiRequest } from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-request';
import Geocoding from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding';
import Matrix from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/matrix';
```

When I do this, I get 3 similar errors for these 3 imports

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-request'. '<path>/node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-request.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-request';`ts(7016)
```

Next I tried to just import the base mapbox library.

```js
import * as _ from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk';

import { MapiRequest } from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-request';
import Geocoding from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding';
import Matrix from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/matrix';
```

Obviously this doesnt work (theres no top level module in the `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` package) BUT miraculously Typescript is suddenly able to find the typings for `MapiRequest`, `Geocoding`, and `Matrix`, and the error is on that first line as

```
File '<path>/node_modules/@types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

1- What is happening here?
2- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to install `@types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk` for types and add the types in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["@types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk"],
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I needed `mapbox__mapbox-sdk`. I also think it only happened because I already had some types defined. thanks!

Comment: Still confused why it had different behavior if I imported the whole library vs if I didnt

Comment: here is the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types, and if the answer helped you you can accept it

Comment: Yeah I've seen the docs. Still confused why it had different behavior between the two examples I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

- `@mapbox/mapbox-sdk` version is equal to `@types/mapbox__mapbox-sdk` version
- you must use an api import with path `import mbxClient from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/lib/classes/mapi-client'`